# how to create .htaccess for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess

does anyone know to create `.htaccess` on rails? Guide me please. Thanks.

regards

Comment: Apache provides a [guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) you may find useful.

Comment: `.htaccess` files are for apache only, so I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: Which server? Rails does not run on top of Apache. It runs on top of Rack servers (Mongrel, Webrick, et al). There is not an exact equivalent on those. 

If you are running Phusion Passenger in an Apache environment, don't think of it as running inside of Apache. It "looks" like it is, but it's mostly just a way to bring Ruby side-by-side to Apache, not actually inside of it.

Comment: Have you looked into `config/routes.rb`? If you used `.htaccess` for its `mod_rewrite`, forget it!

Answer (score 2):

You just create the .htaccess file on your website document root. In apache, that would be the document root of your website (could be something like /var/www/your_website.com, or whatever you specified).

Comment: You can't put an .htaccess inside your rails app. It won't work. .htaccess is specific to the apache webserver and it's about the apache document root.