# How to gracefully redirect ember hash location to history location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ember.js, thin, pushstate

My current Ember router is using the `hash` location and I want to switch to using `history` location. I'm using Rails with `thin` to serve up the app and hosting on Heroku.

**How do I gracefully change the location setting so links that users have bookmarked don't suddenly start breaking?**

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845048/client-side-javascript-app-url-routing-with-no-hash-tag/16554242#16554242) to edit the `.htaccess` file, but as far as I can see, Rails [doesn't run on top of Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468730/how-to-create-htaccess-for-ruby-on-rails), so this isn't a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this client-side. Add something like this to your app:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    if (location.hash) {
     //map known hash values to urls, redirect as needed...
    }
  }
});
```